# Bootstrap datepicker issue in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap modal having a form with one field of date. Initially i was facing issue with the date, But one way or the other i managed to display the bootstrap datepicker. But there is a little issue. Actually when i click on the date text box it does't work for the first attempt and then i have to click on some other text boxes and then click back again in the date text box then it works. Here is my code

Modal having date text box

```
<input onClick="display_date()" size="16" type="text" value="" id="expiry_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" readonly>
```

Js file

```
function display_date(){
$('#expiry_date').datetimepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0
});
```

}

I also tried to use js code in modal without function given below but it did't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#expiry_date').datetimepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0
});
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle or snippet demo?? then i can help you?

Comment: don't create the `datetimepicker` `onclick` - put the initialization of the dtp in a `$(document).ready`

Comment: Checked with $(document).ready – but its working the same as i told.

Comment: First, remove the onclick from your input field. Next, delete the `display_date` functon completely. Then wrap your second code block in a `$(document).ready` - if that still doesn't work, you'll need to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example if you'd like assistance https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: are you confusing  [jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) with [boostrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)? Can you clarify wich plug in are you using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap datetimepicker

Comment: @Kashif in  [bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) the option **weekStart** doesn't exist. So, please, can you say which exact plug in you  are using?

Comment: He's using the bootstrap datepicker as far as I can tell. The above code works for datepicker but not for datetimepicker. Change `datetimepicker` to `datepicker` and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call datepicker() on the datepicker element when it is actually rendered. This means when the modal with the element is rendered.

If necessary put a breakpoint before the

`$('#expiry_date').datetimepicker`
and make sure the element is there in the DOM.

Remove your onclick method, you don't need to initialize the datepicker when there is a click event. This probably caused the weird - one time opened, one time not - behaviour.

Comment: Can you elaborate What you mean

Comment: You should call $('#expiry_date').datepicker() when the expiry_date is an existing element in your DOM. Could it be that the modal HTML is not there yet when you call datepicker() on the expiry-date object?
If so, make sure to call $('#expiry_date').datepicker() after your modal is rendered. 
It seems to me the datepicker is now only initiated after a click event, cause then it gets to your display_date function

Comment: Checked your reply now. But i did the same, and it worked, Thanks Alot